# Mostrar lista ordenada desde un for

Tags: java

Necesito listar los nombres de los alumnos por modulo, estos objetos se relacionan a través de otra lista, paso a detallar:

Alumno (idAlumno,nombreAlumno)   --> ArrayList
Modulo(idModulo,nombreModulo)    -->ArrayList
Nota(idAlumno,IdModulo,nota)    -->clase que relaciona Alumno y Modulo - ArrayList

por ejemplo:

```
   Alumno a1 = new Alumno (2,"pepe");
   Alumno a2 = new Alumno (4,"juan");
   Modulo m1 = new Modulo (3,"Biología");
   Modulo m2 = new Modulo (1,"Matematica");

   Nota n1 = new Nota (2,3)   ---> Pepe , Biología
   Nota n2 = new Nota (4,3)      --->juan, Biología
```

Lo que necesito es listar los alumnos por modulo, es decir, imprimir por pantalla los alumnos que estén en determinado modulo para lo que debo utilizar la lista Notas que relaciona ambas clases, he intentado con varios for anidados y obtengo el resultado, la duda es cual es la mejor forma de ordenar esta lista que obtengo para que me liste los alumnos por modulo por ejemplo:

```
    MODULO = Biologia| NOMBRE ALUMNO = "pepe"
    MODULO = Biologia | NOMBRE ALUMNO = "juan"
```

Código:
System.out.println("ALUMNOS POR MODULO");

```
            for (int j = 0; j < listaNota().size(); j++) {
                
                  for (int i = 0; i < listaAlumno().size(); i++) {
                    
                      if (listaNota().get(j).getId_alumno() == listaAlumno().get(i).getId()) {
                         System.out.println( "MODULO = "+ listaModulo().get(j).getNombre() + " |  NOMBRE ALUMNO = " +listaAlumno().get(i).getNombre());
                      }
              
            }
                    
        }
```

Comment: La pregunta no está clara: ¿hay un hay un arrayList<Alumnos>, un ArrayList<Modulo> y un ArrayList<Nota> ? Lo que buscas es ordenar por modulo, entonces para cada Nota hay que buscar el correspondiente modulo y los alumnos?

Comment: exactamente, has entendido bien. tengo que ordenar por modulo, de donde obtengo esos valores? del ArrayList<Nota> que relaciona las otras 2 clases (Alumno y Modulo). Creo que lo mejor será que cree otro array solo con el resultado de los for anidados y después ordenar...

Comment: lo que dificulta el problema son las estructuras de datos, hay que recorrer todo el arraylist para encontrar lo buscado y esto varias veces. Tendrías que pre-procesar los datos: ordenarlos o transformarlos a un map para facilitar el trabajo.

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución utiliza *stream* API para generar mapas y ordena el ArrayList de notas.

Ordenar ArrayList de notas hace que la salida esté ordenada por módulos, para eso utilizo un *Comparator*, aunque se puede implementar Comparable en la clase Nota. El orden es por idModulo y Luego idAlumno.

```
Comparator<Nota> byModule = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Nota o1, Nota o2) {
        int dif = Integer.compare(o1.getIdModulo(), o2.getIdModulo());
        if(dif != 0) {
            return dif;
        }else {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getIdAlumno(), o2.getIdAlumno());
        }
    }
};
```

Genero dos mapas para para alumnos y módulos usando *stream* , los mapas tienen el formato [id, nombre], ejemplo [ 1, Matemática] lo que permite acceder al nombre mediante el id

```
Map<Integer, String> mapaModulos ;
Map<Integer, String> mapaAlumnos ;
    
    mapaAlumnos = alumnos.stream()
            .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(Alumno::getIdAlumno, Alumno::getNombre));
    
    mapaModulos = modulos.stream()
            .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(Modulo::getIdModulo, Modulo::getNombreModulo));
```

Por último la salida final, primero ordenar ArrayList notas y luego con un **for** recorrer notas y obtener los datos de los mapas:

```
notas.sort(byModule);
for (int i = 0 ; i < notas.size() ; i++) {
    Nota nota = notas.get(i);
    System.out.println("MODULO = "+mapaModulos.get(nota.getIdModulo()) +
                       " | ALUMNO = "+ mapaAlumnos.get( nota.getIdAlumno()));
}
```

Recurso para entender como se generaron los maps [aquí](https://ricardogeek.com/como-usar-el-metodo-tomap-de-los-collectors-de-java-8/)

**Solución iterativa**, requiere que los arraysList estén ordenados, usar el Comparator ya indicado para el arrayList notas y ordenar por id los arraysList de módulos y alumnos por id.

Sea notas[ (1,1), (3,1), (5,1), ...,(idAlumno, idModulo)...]

Voy a recorrer el notas mientras idModulo de la clase nota coincida con el idModulo de la clase Modulo. durante este recorrido voy a buscar dentro de el array de alumnos los idAlumnos que coincidan con el IdAlumno de la clase Nota (1,3,5).

El for externo recorre el arrayslist de módulos, el while interno recorre notas mientras coincida idModulo de notas con idModulo de modulo. Por ultimo el if se ocupa filtrar/mostrar el alumno correspondiente. Prestar especial atención a los indices y cuando aumentan.

```
int indexNotas = 0;  // indice para recorrer el array de notas
int indexAlumno = 0; // indice para recorrer el array de alumnos
//recorrer el arraylist de modulos
for(int modIndex = 0; modIndex < modulos.size(); modIndex++) {
    Modulo temp = modulos.get(modIndex);
    while(indexNotas < notas.size() &&  notas.get(indexNotas).getIdModulo() == temp.getIdModulo()) {
        // si idAlumno == idAlumno indicado en Nota muestro el mensaje 
        if(alumnos.get(indexAlumno).getIdAlumno() == notas.get(indexNotas).getIdAlumno()) {
            System.out.println("MODULO = "+temp.getNombreModulo()+" | NOMBRE ALUMNO = "
                +alumnos.get(indexAlumno).getNombre()+" | NOTA = "+notas.get(indexNotas).getNota());
            // aumento el indice de notas
            indexNotas++;
        }
        // aumento el indice de alumnos 
        indexAlumno++;
    }
    // reinicio el indice de alumnos para buscar en el siguiere modulo
    indexAlumno = 0;
}
```

Para mayor claridad ver [aquí](https://gist.github.com/lucasDRR/28df7990eecc832a744be1c3cd97f236)

Comment: La pregunta parece una tarea de clase y normalmente los profesores no permiten que se usen las herramientas ya disponibles, si no que quieren que se hagan las cosas *a mano*. Por ejemplo, en este caso, si pone un ejercicio para que aprendan a recorrer estructuras de datos y filtrar/seleccionar, usar bucles anidados etc... no creo que usar stream() sea correcto. Además, si está aprendiendo lo básico, meterle referencias de métodos, streams, collectors... a lo mejor es un poco *too much*!. No digo que la respuesta esté mal... solo que a lo mejor vale la pena hacerlo *a mano* aunque sea más lioso

Comment: Coincido con lo que lo que dices @Benito-B pero utilizar demasiados fors anidados me da dolor de estomago (ja), ademas siempre es bueno aprender algo nuevo. voy a agregar la versión iterativa. saludos